# Can I push HTML files to my app?

Tags: ios6, push

I have some help files written in HTML that I would like to update occasionally without updating the entire app and doing a resubmission to the app store.

Is there a way I can "push" those files to the app without creating an "update" to the app in the app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you reference the files from a remote server there is no way of persisting data into an app. Even when you reference the files remotely you run the risk of Apple Rejecting your app. They do this to avoid insidious code, especially if content is posted dynamically. You can't modify your bundle once it is sandboxed. You can change your Documents folder in theory, but like I said, Apple may reject your app because of the insidious nature.